# How to query values in a dictionary of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list in `Python` and it's a dictionary contains a dictionary.

```
{'METTS MARK': {'salary': 365788, 'po': 1}, 'HARRY POTTER':{'salary': 3233233, 'po': 0}
```

How do I calculate the number of records with `'po' = 1`?

I tried this:

```
sum = 0
for key, values in DIC:
     if values[po] == 1:
        sum = sum + 1
```

But it returns: `too many values to unpack`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `DIC.items()` to get the `key` and `value`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `sum` and sum over the condition:

```
total = sum(values.get('po') == 1 for values in DIC.values())
```

which is equivalent to (as @VPfB says):

```
total = sum (1 for item in DIC.values() if item.get('po') == 1)
```

but the latter is a bit less efficient.

You should also use `'po'` instead of `po` since it is a string, and you better use `.get('po')` since this guarantees that it will work if `'po'` is not part of *every* dictionary.

I think **you forgot to use `.items()` in your `for` loop**. By iterating over the dictionary, you iterate **over the keys** and in this case, you cannot *unpack* your keys into tuples with two elements.

Nevertheless using a generator, this will be more memory efficient (probably faster as well) and it is clean code. Furthermore by iterating directly over the `.values` instead of the `.items` one expects an increase in performance because one saves on packing and unpacking.

Comment: You should use .get('po', 0). In your version you will have exception because of None. And sum() work faster with lists then with generators. So it will be better to use sum([values.get('po', 0) == 1 for values in DIC.values()])

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov: but given the key is not present, `None` is returned and `None == 1` will generate `False` (and thus count as zero). It could be possible that `values['po']` is `2`, you don't want to count these two times, you want to eliminate these.

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov: `None` can be compared with `1`, `None == False` fails. Furthermore it makes code more robust if the OP changes their mind and want to filter with `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: You might prefer `sum (1 for item in DIC.values() if item.get('po') == 1)` for readability. Just a matter of individual preferences.

Comment: @VPfB: This is indeed more readable, but a bit less efficient. Furthermore this is a well known pattern. I will however for reference add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like this:

```
a = {
     'METTS MARK': {'salary': 365788, 'po': 1},
     'HARRY POTTER': {'salary': 3233233, 'po': 0}
     }

print(len([b for b in a.values() if b.get('po')==1]))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Here we are creating a list of dictionaries where the key `po==1`. And then we calculate the length of the list.